# I'm getting 404 when run it on terminal and getting 200 on idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Code:

```
import requests
file = open("test.txt")
for url in file:
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.status_code)
```

---------test.txt-----------

```
https://www.google.com
```

O/p in Terminal:

> 404

When i use it in Idle:

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("https://google.com")
>>> response.status_code
200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `url` from your file will have a newline at its end. Try `strip()`ing it:

```
for url in file:
    response = requests.get(url.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

you overlook a simple part. just add `.readlines()` after `file`. By this I mean the following:

```py
import requests
file= open("file.txt")
for url in file:
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.status_code)
```

This works for me. Hope it helps :)